# MongoDB query string with 2 or 3 vowels

Tags: regex, mongodb

I've a query that only finds the names that contains 3 or more vowels, but I have no idea how to do it.

Any suggestion on what I need to look for? I already tried with regex but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me:

consecutive vowels:

```
db.test.find({"testProperty":{$regex:'[aeiou]{3}'}})
```

total vowels:

```
db.test.find({"testProperty":{$regex:'([aeiou].*){3}'}})
```

Comment: That only works when the vowels follow each other, it would not select Samuel, for example.